# I converted scrolling background to a bitmap, which now uses more memory, but scrolls much faster, how/why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

So I'm in the process of making an as3 game with a scrolling cave background. I have it set up to randomly generate a 30x30 cave (900 tiles). I would generate the cave then add all of the tiles as children to a "Background" movieclip. I was having some issues with it lagging so I decided to convert the background to a bitmap. Before I did this trace(System.totalMemory); output a value of around 20,000,000. Afterwards it's around 28,000,000, however the lagging/background-scrolling issues I had seem to have stopped. Why would it use more memory, and why would it alleviate my scrolling issues despite this? Here's the important part of the code.

```
    //My cave is 1800 x 1800 pixels
    var bitMapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1800, 1800);
        //Drawing the cave to a bitmapdata
        bitMapData.draw(background1);
        var bitMap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitMapData);
        //Removing all of the tiles from the background 
        while(background1.numChildren > 0) {
            background1.removeChildAt(0);
        }
        //adding the bitmap to my background
        background1.addChild(bitMap);
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a wrong design altogether anyway but I guess a good study case for you. Of course scrolling background cannot be done this way whether with a bunch of displayed tiles or a big background. Best way is dynamic drawing and second is tiles where only the visible tiles are displayed.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what you mean by dynamic drawing? I couldn't find anything related to creating a scrolling background with it.

Comment: and also why did you say that a scrolling background "cannot" be done this way? It seems to be working currently.

Comment: There's a difference between something working and something done the right way. A scrolling background cannot be done this way because it's too CPU expensive. It works for you because you manage to keep the BitmapData size small but with a bigger setup lag will start to appear meaning the solution is wrong in principle.

Comment: Dynamic drawing is done by drawing only the part that you need on screen via BitmapData that fits the screen size or graphics drawing. This is done via matrice and is much more efficient because it only draws and display what you need on screen at all time. It does involve a lot more math and that's why non coder or beginners tend to stay away from it since they are not concerned with optimization.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm gonna give it a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, drawing a `MovieClip` is always done through vector renderer, this involves querying its structure, querying display list and more, also in case those MCs of yours have uneven scale (unequal and not in the line of powers of 2) even bitmap rendering is slowed. Having one `Bitmap` instead of 900 MCs lowers display list traversal time by a great margin (900 vs 1 - isn't it a decent improvement?). Of course, bitmaps occupy more memory than MCs, but this is same old memory vs performance issue that every programmer hits sooner or later. Don't worry about this 8M bitmap, just don't make too many bitmaps this big for mobile platform.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would a scrolling background typically be done? There are plenty of rpg games (Early Final Fantasy games for instance) With huge seamless scrolling backgrounds.

Comment: You create two `Bitmap` object which refer to one single `BitmapData` object, and display them both at once, and shift the invisible bitmap rightwards once there's an empty space on the right.

Comment: When the only transforms on your background movieclip are x position or y position you could also cache the movieclip as a bitmap with the 'cacheAsBitmap' property. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001283.html#374074

Comment: @StefanvandeVooren Right, but 900 MCs are still decent overhead over two bitmaps.

Comment: True, I only pointed to the cacheAsBitmap property so you do not need to write the code to convert your movieclip children into bitmaps.